# token recognition error at: '#i' when parsing c grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I am trying to parse a very simple C file using the antlr v4 grammar found at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4. 
The file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello world!");
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to parse the file like this:

```
public void parse(FileInputStream myFile) throws IOException {
  ANTLRInputStream source = new ANTLRInputStream(myFile);
  CLexer lexer = new CLexer(source);
  CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
  CParser parser = new CParser(stream);
  ParseTree tree = parser.primaryExpression();
  ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new MyParseListener(), tree);
}
```

As i am trying to parse it i will get the error.

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: '#i'
```

Is there another step i need to do to handle preprocessing? Is the C grammar incomplete?

Comment: "#include" is not part of the C grammar. It, along with #define, #ifdef, etc. are handled by the *preprocessor*, a phase separate from parsing and compilation.

Comment: How would i handle this in antlr then? Do i need to precompile my code before parsing it? Do i need to add rules for preprocessing to be able to parse my code?

Comment: Either approach would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar provided does not support #include directives as far as I can see in the current committed version.

In fact the #include directive is not part of the C grammar as such, and therefor it is not treated typically by a compiler but by a preprocessor

[Definition of the C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)